# Why use $\forall$ instead of $\in$?

Tags: notation

So, here are two ways to say what I interpret as the same statement:

> $f_i(x,y)\geq0 \hspace{0.85cm} \forall i \{0,1,2\}$

which implies that $f_0(x,y) \geq0$ and $f_1(x,y)\geq0$ and $f_2(x,y)\geq0$

but doesn't

> $f_i(x,y)\geq0 \hspace{0.85cm}\{i\in\mathbb{Z}|i\in[0,2]\}$

imply the same thing?

Is there another reason why these different notations are used, besides the fact that the one consumes less space than the other? Apologies if one of these notations falls into a specific category of mathematics without my knowledge. I am not fully taught (evidently).

Any responses are appreciated.

Comment: I would say both are syntactically incorrect; you should have both $\forall$ and $\in$ in a correct presentation.

Comment: @Ian How would you present them?

Comment: I'd like to point out that $[0,2]\neq\{0,1,2\}$ but rather equals every single real number $n$, including an infinite number of decimals, such that $0\le n\le2$. However I don't believe that's the nature of your query.

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor I did however specify that $i$ is an element of the set of integers, hence the infinite decimal values between $0$ and $2$ are excluded from the interval.

Comment: @joshuaheckroodt Of course, silly me. Perhaps I need glasses ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, in formal mathematics, the condition should come first:
$$ \forall i \in \{0,1,2\} \; f_i(x,y) \ge 0 $$

Comment: So you can in fact use them in the same statement? Is this a common occurrence?

Comment: Yes.  Your "$\forall i\; \{0,1,2\}$" is wrong, because there is no indication of the relationship between $i$ and $\{0,1,2\}$.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: This is very interesting. I never knew this—in fact, I always put the condition *last*!

Comment: One also sees things like $f_i(x,y)\geq0, i\in\{0,1,2\},$ but that is a distinctly _less_ formal way of writing the statement.

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor Suppose we write "$x^2$ integrated from $0$ to $1$" as $x^2\int_0^1dx$? That probably looks weird to you. Putting $\forall$ to the right of things it's meant to apply to looks weird to me. (And the two notations actually have a lot in common.)

Comment: @DavidK You make perfect sense, and the analogy helps with the understanding. And also, when would you prefer to write in _formal_ mathematical statements rather than informal?

Comment: The order becomes really important in cases where you have both existential ($\exists$) and universal ($\forall$) quantifiers: $\exists x \forall y \; A(x,y)$ has a very different meaning than $\forall y \exists x \; A(x,y)$.

Comment: And  $\exists x \; A(x,y) \forall y$ would be terribly confusing.